# Bind XAML Image to IRandomAccessStreamReference

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, uwp

Windows UWP C# APIs make use of IRandomAccessStreamReference, and whilst I can get a byte array as below, I can't use the methods I would expect to find in BitmapImage (from WPF) to produce a Bitmap image; even if I could, I feel this solution is far too clumbsy and tedius to be the expected means to do so, and it abuses asynchronous loading.

This compiles in UWP:

```
private static byte[] GetBytes(IRandomAccessStreamReference r)
{
    var stream = r.OpenReadAsync().GetResults();

    var bytes = new byte[stream.Size];
    stream.ReadAsync(bytes.AsBuffer(), (uint)stream.Size, InputStreamOptions.None).GetResults();

    return bytes;
}
```

This doesn't compile in UWP due to `BeginInit`, `CacheOption`, `BitmapCacheOption`, `StreamSource`, and `EndInit` being undefined:

```
public static BitmapImage ToImage(byte[] array)
{
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(array))
    {
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad; // here
        image.StreamSource = ms;
        image.EndInit();
        return image;
    }
}
```

How should I best use an IRandomAccessStreamReference to display an Image with UWP?

My specific use case is dealing with Windows contacts, for which I want to construct a collection, and bind to it; something like:

```
public void InitialiseSomeViewModel()
{
    var contactStore = ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
    contactStore.GetResults().FindContactsAsync().GetResults();

    ContactInfo = c.Select(x => new MyContactEntity { Name = x.Name, Thumbnail = x.Thumbnail});
}
```

Note that `Thumbnail` in this example is `IRansomAccessStreamReference`

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach to it, is to use the ***InMemoryRandomAccessStream*** with the ***IValueConverter*** interface. So you can decode the byte arrays doing the runtime binding.

first you need to specify the valueconverter in the Image Control in XAML.

Then you can use the following IValueConverter to decode the byte array.

```
class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null || !(value is byte[]))
            return null;
        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(ms.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
            {
                writer.WriteBytes((byte[])value);
                writer.StoreAsync().GetResults();
            }
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(ms);

            //other specification

            return image;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```